# Loop over API data and display multiple search items in the DOM with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, api, async-await, axios, dom-events

I'm trying to set up a search API app, using the https://restcountries.eu/ API and axios.

I've managed to display everything in the DOM, as I want. However, if I search for "United", or something with only part of the name. It either displays undefined or if I loop though it'll only display the last search item. I'd like to bring all the search items into the DOM, under any search criteria I input.

Below is the HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="search-container">
      <form id="form" class="form">
        <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search for country..." />
      </form>
    </div>
    <main id="main">
      <div id="map" class="google-map"></div>
    </main>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.21.1/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here's the JS:

```
const APIURL = 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/'
// const GOOGLE_MAPS_API = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDhlU1KMTlTh4C__bTJBxbVA-s7wvQbO9E&callback=initMap'
const main = document.getElementById('main')
const form = document.getElementById('form')
const search = document.getElementById('search')



async function getCountryData(name) {
    try {
        
        const { data } = await axios.get(APIURL + name)

        data.forEach(res => {
            let countryArr = res

            createCountryCard(countryArr)
        } )

       
    } catch (err) {
        
        if(err.response.status == 404) {
            
            createErrorCard('No countries found')
         
            setTimeout(() => { 
                main.innerHTML = ''}
                , 1500);
        }
    }
}

function createCountryCard(country) {
    const cardHTML = `
    <div class="content-container">
        <div class="card">
         <div class="wrapper">
             <div class="card-title">
              <h2>${country.name}</h2>
              <h4>Capital: ${country.capital}</h4>
              <h5>Population: ${country.population.toLocaleString('en')}</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="card-image">
          <img
            src="${country.flag}"
            alt="${country.name +'-flag'}"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="map-content">
          <div id="map" class="google-map"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <ul class="card-list">
            <li><strong>Region:</strong> ${country.region}</li>
            <li><strong>Subregion:</strong> ${country.subregion}</li>
            <li><strong>Currency:</strong> ${country.currencies[0].name}<span> ${country.currencies[0].symbol}</span></li>
            <li><strong>Spoken Language:</strong> ${country.languages[0].name}</li>
            <li><strong>Timezone:</strong> ${country.timezones}</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  `

  main.innerHTML = cardHTML

  console.log(country)
}

function createErrorCard(msg) {
    const cardHTML = `
    <div class="card">
        <h1>${msg}</h1>
    </div>
    `
    main.innerHTML = cardHTML

  
}

// Search Input
form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    const countryName = search.value

    if(countryName) {
        getCountryData(countryName)

        search.value = ''
    }
})
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: That's happening because you're overwrtting the `innerHTML` with `main.innerHTML = cardHTML` everytime `createCountryCard()` is called. What you need to do is append the country card instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`main.innerHTML = cardHTML` line in `createCountryCard()` function overwrites the content of the `#main` element with each loop iteration. That's why you are only getting the last item from your search results. Try changing it to `main.innerHTML += cardHTML`.